# PowerShell Invoke-Command -AsJob

Tags: powershell

The script I wrote is pretty long but works fine except for one problem. When I have more `jobs` for the same `$Server` it's only submitting one job and doesn't execute the second or third job for the same `$Server`.

The input comes from a CSV-file in this format:

```
\\domain\SHARE\Target3, 0
BELSFBRUS0131, E:\DEPARTMENTS\CBR\SHARE\Target2, 0
BELSFBRUS0131, E:\DEPARTMENTS\CBR\SHARE\Target4, 0
```

In the example above the script only starts 2 jobs, one for the UNC-path `Target3` and one for `Target2` on `BELSFBRUS0131`, these are executed fine. But there's no job launched for `Target4`to the same server... Is this maybe a restriction of `Invoke-Command` to only launch once to each server?

Thank you for your help guys.

Here is the important part of the script (due to max. 30.000 lines, I limited it):

```
Foreach ($_ in $File) {

# Starting jobs

    if (($Server -eq "UNC") -or ($Server -eq "$env:COMPUTERNAME")) {
        Write-Host "$(Get-TimeStamp) $env:COMPUTERNAME > Start job: local > $Server, $Target, $OlderThanDays, $LogFolder, $CleanFolders" -ForegroundColor Gray
        $arrayAllJobs += Start-Job -ScriptBlock $JobCall -ArgumentList ($Target, $OlderThanDays, $Server, $LogFolder, $CleanFolders) -Name DelFiles
    }
    else {
          Write-Host "$(Get-TimeStamp) $env:COMPUTERNAME > Start job: Remote > $Server, $Target, $OlderThanDays, $LogFolder, $CleanFolders" -ForegroundColor Gray        
          $arrayAllJobs += Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $JobCall -ArgumentList ($Target, $OlderThanDays, $Server, $LogFolder, $CleanFolders) -ComputerName "$Server.grouphc.net" -Authentication Credssp -Credential $Credentials -AsJob -JobName DelFiles
    }  
}
#__________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
# Checking jobs

Write-Host "`n$(Get-TimeStamp) $env:COMPUTERNAME > Waiting for all jobs to finish.." -ForegroundColor Cyan; Wait-Job -Job $arrayAllJobs
Write-Host "`n$(Get-TimeStamp) $env:COMPUTERNAME > The targets were:" -ForegroundColor Cyan; $arrayAllPaths | Format-List

foreach ($Job in $arrayAllJobs) {
    if ($job.State -ne 'Completed') {
        # Write-Host ($Job.ChildJobs[0].JobStateInfo.Reason.Message) -ForegroundColor Red
        $arrayJobError += $Job.ChildJobs[0].JobStateInfo.Reason.Message
        $HTMLarrayJobError += $Job.ChildJobs[0].JobStateInfo.Reason.Message +"<br>"
    } 
    #<# Reported success:
    else {
        Write-Host (Receive-Job $Job) -ForegroundColor Green 
    } #>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it related to the fact that all of your jobs are being created with the same JobName:

```
 Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $JobCall -ArgumentList ($Target, $OlderThanDays, $Server, $LogFolder, $CleanFolders) -ComputerName "$Server.grouphc.net" -Authentication Credssp -Credential $Credentials -AsJob -JobName DelFiles
```

so you're trying to create two jobs with the same name, on the same server.

Comment: I just tried removing the part `-JobName DelFiles` but no luck. It seems like `Invoke-Command` is limited to one job per `$Server`? Although local jobs are started multiple times correctly..

Answer (score 0):

I made a previous error in my script, that was the reason why the seconde server didn't arrive in the loop. I'm sorry everyone, my bad.